# Why does this code not output the expected output?

Tags: c, fread

This can be a good question for finding bugs.
No? Okay for beginners at least.

```
#define SIZE 4
int main(void){
  int chars_read = 1;
  char buffer[SIZE + 1] = {0};  
  setvbuf(stdin, (char *)NULL, _IOFBF, sizeof(buffer)-1);  
  while(chars_read){
    chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof('1'), SIZE, stdin);
    printf("%d, %s\n", chars_read, buffer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Using the above code, I am trying to read from a file using redirection `./a.out < data`. Contents of input file:

```
1line
2line
3line
4line
```

But I am not getting the expected output, rather some graphical characters are mixed in.
What is wrong?

---

Hint: (Courtesy Alok)

- `sizeof('1') == sizeof(int)`
- sizeof("1") == sizeof(char)*2

So, use 1 instead :-)

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371292/buffered-reading-from-stdin-using-fread-in-c/2378520#2378520) for buffered IO example using fread.

Comment: I don't know C, but it may be a text encoding thing.

Comment: i guess not, because with using scanf, i am getting the correct output.

Comment: `fread(buffer, sizeof('1'), SIZE, stdin);` why `sizeof('1')`? just use `1` instead.

Comment: @Gentlmean: its the same thing.

Comment: and how does `chars_read` get incremented?

Comment: @Gentleman: fread returns the numbers of characters read. So, if fread stops reading, chars_read == 0 and while loop is exited.

Comment: Note that `sizeof('1')` is not necessarily 4, it is `sizeof(int)`.  There is no guarantee that the size of an `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: See NVL, I actually showed you the error, `sizeof('1')` :-)

Comment: @Elite: but you didnt point that it was the error :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `'1'` is `int` in C, not `char`, so you are reading `SIZE*sizeof(int)` bytes in each `fread`.  If `sizeof(int)` is greater than 1 (on most modern computers it is), then you are reading past the storage for `buffer`.  This is one of the places where C and C++ are different: in C, character literals are of type `int`, in C++, they are of type `char`.

So, you need `chars_read = fread(buffer, 1, SIZE, stdin);` because `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

In fact, I would write your loop as:

```
while ((chars_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer - 1)) > 0) {
    buffer[chars_read] = 0; /* In case chars_read != sizeof buffer - 1.
                               You may want to do other things in this case,
                               such as check for errors using ferror. */
    printf("%d, %s\n", chars_read, buffer);
}
```

To answer your another question, `'\0'` is the `int` 0, so `{'\0'}` and `{0}` are equivalent.

For `setvbuf`, my documentation says:

> The `size` argument may be given as zero to obtain deferred optimal-size buffer allocation as usual.

Why are you commenting with `\\` instead of `//` or `/* */`? :-)

*Edit*: Based upon your edit of the question, `sizeof("1")` is wrong, `sizeof(char)` is correct.

`sizeof("1")` is 2, because `"1"` is a `char` array containing two elements: `'1'` and `0`.

Comment: \\ typo i was frustrated :P. What documentation do you use?

Comment: On linux, `man` - otherwise see POSIX: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html.  Also, you don't want `sizeof("1")`, see my edit.

Comment: sizeof("1")! saved again. i am overlooking everything!

Comment: I asked nvl about the `sizeof('1')` but I guess he overlooked it.

Comment: @Elite: You asked, but you didnt say that was the error. So, I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a byte-by-byte way to fread the lines from a file using redirection ./a.out < data.

Produces the expected output at least ...  :-)

```
/*

Why does this code not output the expected output ?,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378264/why-does-this-code-not-output-the-expected-output

compile with:
gcc -Wall -O3 fread-test.c

create data:
echo $'1line\n2line\n3line\n4line' > data

./a.out < data

*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main(void) 
{

   int i=0, countNL=0;
   char singlechar = 0;
   char linebuf[SIZE + 1] = {0};
   setvbuf(stdin, (char *)NULL, _IOFBF, sizeof(linebuf)-1);  

   while(fread(&singlechar, 1, 1, stdin))     // fread stdin byte-by-byte
   {
      if ( (singlechar == '\n') )
      {
         countNL++;
         linebuf[i] = '\0';
         printf("%d:  %s\n", countNL, linebuf);
         i = 0;
      } else {
         linebuf[i] = singlechar; 
         i++;
      }
   }

   if ( i > 0 )    // if the last line was not terminated by '\n' ...
   {
      countNL++;
      linebuf[i] = '\0';
      printf("%d:  %s\n", countNL, linebuf);
   }

 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

char buffer[SIZE + 1] = {0};

This isn't doing what you expect, it is making buffer point to a one byte region in the programs constant data segment.  I.e this will corrupt SIZE amount of bytes and possibly cause a memory protection fault.  Always initialize C strings with strcpy() or equivalent.

Comment: Wrong! It does exactly what i intend to do with it.

Comment: @gregery: `char buffer[SIZE+1] = {0};` is perfectly valid.  It sets each element of `buffer` to `0`.

Comment: Ok so it's valid, but I would rewrite it because it's bad style.  The fact that the buffer is filled with '0' is not obvious and would require a reading the c standard to find out how partial initializations are filled.  I never use compile time initialization on an array with variable content so it looks wrong to me.