# Bottleneck from comparing strings

Tags: c++, string

This is a follow up question to [Char* vs String Speed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3989111/363829). 
I have declared the following variables:

```
std::vector<std::string> siteNames_;
std::vector<unsigned int> ids_;
std::vector<std::string> names_;
```

I call this function tens of thousands of times and is a major bottleneck. Is there a more efficient way to compare strings? The answer must be cross-platform compatible.

```
unsigned int converter::initilizeSiteId(unsigned int siteNumber){
    unsigned int siteId = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ids_.size(); i ++){
        if (siteNames_[siteNumber].compare(names_[i]) == 0){
            siteId = ids_[i];
            break; // Once found, will stop searching and break out of for loop
        }
    }
    if (siteId == 0)
        std::cerr << "Could not find ID for site number " << siteNumber << std::endl;

    return siteId;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a definition for `names_`. In any case, if you're doing lookup why don't you use a `std::map` or `std::/boost::/tr1::unordered_map` instead of a linear search? That's what they're for.

Comment: @GMan, typo of the declarations sorry. I have never used `std::map` or that particular boost function. I will look into those. Would you be able to provide an example please?

Comment: How big is siteNames_? If you can guarantee that it will always be in sorted order, then you could try a binary search. And to really optimize, store siteNames_[siteNumber] in a temporary variable to prevent looking it up constantly. EDIT: To echo the other comments, a map would handle binary search for you.

Comment: @Chrisaycock, unfortunately siteNames_ is not in sorted order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) or [unordered map](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/stl_unordered_map.htm) instead. Then you can do this:

```
std::map<string, int>names_;
// ...

unsigned int converter::initilizeSiteId(unsigned int siteNumber){
    unsigned int siteId = 0;
    std::map<string, int>::iterator i = names_.find(siteNames_[siteNumber]);
    if (i != names_.end()){
        siteId = i->second;
    }
    else (siteId == 0)
        std::cerr << "Could not find ID for site number " << siteNumber << std::endl;

    return siteId;
}
```

This will perform in O(log n) time rather than the O(n) you had before.

There are other options if you have a sorted list, such as [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I am getting errors when I try to compile this code, I also have tried `std::map::iterator i` and that fails. What is mapiterator?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: I've updated it a bit. You need template parameters, and `names_` needs to be a map, and it should match your names to the ids. So `names_["bob"] = 2` for example.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Well, what are the errors and what is your code? Also, this should be covered in a C++ book, [do you have one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: @GMan, I tend to favor C++ Primer, 5th Edition  http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Plus-5th-Stephen-Prata/dp/0672326973

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: well surely that book has a section about maps. Reading through that will give you a lot of very useful knowledge. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Actually maps are barely covered, they only have two pages in Appendix G and thats it, hence probably why I am stuck now :p

Comment: @JoshD, I know this is asking alot, but can you provide a map solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989111/char-vs-string-speed-in-c. `names_.insert(std::pair<std::string, unsigned in>(name,id));` isn't working and not sure why

Comment: @Elpez: Ah, you need to be more careful. The title is C++ Primer Plus, not C++ Primer. It matters, especially in this case since C++ Primer is it's own book. In that book (the one you linked), turn to page 1101. Unfortunately, that's a pretty bad book, which is why we don't have it on the list. It's always a bad thing having a bad book. :(

Comment: @Gman, haha that it is, I will have to get some of the recommended books from SO. I tend to use www.cplusplus.com before anything else

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: if that snippet of code is accurate, then you misspelled `int`.

Comment: @JoshD, hahaah that was it! I feel very relieved that I am not completely worthless. Thanks so much, I have seen a significant boost in performance!

Answer (score 0):

If you often look up just a few different siteNumber and call it enough times it could be worthwile to implement a cache to store the latest siteNumber:s. Although since you're only working in memory and not to/from disk I doubt it.